# How to solve favicon.ico 404 errors on b2clogin.com domain?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, favicon

We are using a B2C instance with a custom SignIn user flow. The custom pages are hosted on a Azure storage configured as a static website containing a favicon.ico in the root. The header of the HTML of the custom page contains (among others) a `<link rel="icon" href="<static website>/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />` declaration. When running the website the icon is shown but we still see `https://<b2cdomain>.b2clogin.com/favicon.ico` 404 errors. How can we prevent this error?

Comment: Too few info, hard to tell. You probably did not put `favicon.ico` into that particular root: `https://<b2cdomain>.b2clogin.com/`.

Comment: @stackprotector: That domain is maintained by Microsoft itself. I believe I don't have access to it.

Comment: Sure, but as long as there is no `favicon.ico` in the root, you'll get 404's. Maybe you should not worry too much about it. Having `favicon.ico` in the root is [discouraged/deprecated](https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon). And only IE<=10 still relies on it. Other browsers try to access it only if you don't provide it in another way (like you did).

Comment: Is this icon file is stored at the same place where the HTML files are saved? Do you have configured CORS? Refer below link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-user-flow#3-configure-cors

Comment: Also make sure that image url is not relative. Only absolute path works